# Problem with reorder() graph in ggplot2, with grouped variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data with several values for different regions and different programs, when I try to order my graph from higher to lower accumulated values it works perfectly.

```
datos = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaimeyanez/varios/master/datos.csv")

datos %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(value= sum(Monto)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=reorder(Region,-value), y=value), alpha=.9) +
  labs(title = "Value per group")
```

[Graph without classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKcj4.png)

But if i try to do the same and add a fill aesthetic, it fails

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(Region, Programa) %>% 
  summarise(value= sum(Monto)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=reorder(Region,-value), y=value, fill=Programa), alpha=.9) +
  labs(title = "Value per group")
```

[Graph with classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4La6X.png)

I can change the order manually, but this data is an example and I have to do this whit different grouped variables, so i need to do this in an automatic way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reorder` uses the mean value by default, but your bars show the sum. Change to `x = reorder(Region, -value, FUN = sum)`